# Problems with fixed point equotation regarding the sequence $\left( \sqrt[n]{n} \right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n=\sqrt[n]{n}$ then we find $a_n=( (a_{n-1})^{n-1}+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Therefore we can make a fixed point equotation to find the limit $a$ of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$.

$a = (a^{n-1}+1)^{\frac{1}{n}} \leftrightarrow a^{n-1}(a-1)=1 \leftrightarrow a \neq 1$

But from other proofs we know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1 $. Shouldn't the fixed point equotation have a solution for the correct limit?

Comment: You have $n^{1/n}=e^{\ln(n)/n}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fixed point equation you refer to comes from the following theorem:

> **Theorem:** Let $f$ be a continuous function, and $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence such that $a_{n+1}=f(n)$. If $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n=L$, then $L$ is a fixed point of $f$.

Observe that $f$ in the theorem is a function of $x$, but not of $n$. If you think about it, asking for a fixed point of $(a^{n-1}+1)^{1/n}$ doesn't make sense, as what is $n$?

Comment: As far as I know, it comes from the calculus for limits. E.G. $a_n := \sqrt{2a_{n-1}}$ with $a_0:=1$. Then it follows. $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n=a=lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{2a_{n-1}}=\sqrt{2a}$. Anyhow, I kind of see, that this doesn't really work for my stated equotation, but I cannot explain why it doesn't.

Comment: @ntor The reason it doesn't work is because it doesn't even make sense. You're asking for the fixed point of $(a^{n-1}+1)^{1/n}$. But what is $n$?

Comment: Ah got it! Thank you very much!